# What are the best ways to implement two-factor authentication for a windows domain?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-server-2019, two-factor-authentication

I have been asked to make our end users use two-factor authentication. I haven't had to do this before. I was wondering what the common practices are to do this nowadays? I am running windows 10 client side and windows server 2019 as my domain controller. Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: There are hundreds of companys providing 2FA support for Windows domains. However, I use AuthLite a lot. Simple, fast, cheap, secure and immensly flexible.

Answer (score 1):

Use a multifactor authentication provider, such as Duo MFA.

https://duo.com/product/multi-factor-authentication-mfa